# How to exclude tree nodes of a certain "type" from JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, tree, json.net

Say I have a node tree in string format that I've named `stringTree` that contains nodes of `type: "Category"` that I deem unnecessary in it like this:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Type: "Product",
    Children: [
                  {
                      Id: 1.1,
                      Type: "Product",
                      Children: [
                                    {
                                        Id: 1.1.1,
                                        Type: "Category",
                                        Children: null
                                    },
                                    {
                                        Id: 1.1.2,
                                        Type: "Product",
                                        Children: null
                                    }
                                ]
                  },
                  {
                      Id: 1.2,
                      Type: "Category",
                      Children: null
                  }
              ]
}
```

Note that these unnecessary nodes can be at any level of the tree.

I have this large string that contains my tree which I will deserialize using JsonConvert like so:

`var myTree = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Tree>(treeString);`

Is there a way I could have the deserialization ignore any nodes (and their children) if they have a `type = "Category"`?  Basically meaning this tree would turn out with nodes 1.2, and 1.1.1 trimmed from it after deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a custom deserializer but a simpler approach would be to parse the input string into a tree of `JToken`s and filter out tokens that represent objects with `Type == "Category"`:

```
var jToken = JToken.Parse(treeString);
FilterTree(jToken);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jToken, Formatting.Indented));

// ..................

static void FilterTree(JToken jToken)
{
    var jArr = jToken as JArray;
    if (jArr != null)
        for (int i = jArr.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if ((string)jArr[i]["Type"] == "Category")
                jArr[i].Remove();
        }
    foreach (var child in jToken.Children())
        FilterTree(child);
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HjVngF

Answer (score 0):

Is it a requirement that the filtering be done *during* the deserialization process?  If not, you could just add a short recursive method to your `Tree` class to filter out the unwanted nodes as a post-processing step:

```
public Tree Filter(string typeToRemove)
{
    if (Type == typeToRemove)
        return null;

    if (Children != null)
        Children = Children.Select(c => c.Filter(typeToRemove))
                           .Where(c => c != null)
                           .ToList();
    return this;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var tree = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tree>(json)?.Filter("Category");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NrvUZn